# Reading array-json into dataframe from s3

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

Good day,

I am trying to read a json file from s3 into a Glue Dataframe using:

```
source = '<some s3 location>'
glue_df = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    "s3", {'paths': [source], 'recurse': False}, format='json')
```

The json file itself is someone non-standard, it has the following format:

```
[
  {
    "name": "john",
    "subjects": ["math", "science", "prog"],
    "marks": [92.2, 88.4, 66.7 ]
  },
  {
    "name": "sam",
    "subject": ["science", "prog", "math"],
    "marks": [92.2, 88.4, 66.7 ]
  }
]
```

The idea was to get this into a dataframe in some way and then manipulate it afterwards to get it in the correct format.  On df.show() I get an empty dataframe.

How can I read the data so that I can manipulate it?  One record per row would be fine.

Comment: I verified your code and looks ok. Maybe a typo?  glue_df.show()  instead of df.show()

Comment: If so, you can use from_json() or json_tuple() function to play with that data.

Comment: I ended up using df = spark.read.json(...), which did the trick.  Thank you for looking into this.